# Sujood dua when Praying

Tags: salat

When I’m in sujood after saying subhana rabbial alaa can I glorify allah by saying his names like ya Malik and ya jabbar and etc and than say my dua

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's actually the Sunnah! After you say "subhana rabbial alaa" 3 times (or more), you glorify Allah Subhanu wa Ta'ala then you can make dua in whatever matter you like, based on the Hadith: "The closest a servant is to his Lord is when he is prostrating, so increase the supplication".